# Android data persistency

Tags: android, persistence

I'd like to develop an app which need some data persistency. For some reason, I don't want to use database. And I'd like something similar to the shared preference. But only have one more requirement:

- I hope my data can be persistent across installation. That means even the app uninstalled the data still be stored in Android system safely.

Are there any suggestions? Thanks

P.S.: In iOS, I use the keychain.It works perfectly.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What is the purpose of the data is the app has been uninstalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can think of to ensure non-removal on uninstallation is to write a file somewhere on the external storage. However this is (a) insecure (b) prone to other issues such as users deleting it.

If you are worried about persisting data on *upgrades* then using a database with a ContentProvider you can achieve this fairly easily. Shared Prefs are only really meant for a small number of small values/primitives.

There is also the option of storing something remotely, with a web service if it fits with whatever need you have to retain data when uninstalled/reinstalled.

The majority of questions like yours indicate an issue somewhere else in the way your application is architected, if you provide more detail people here may give you a better solution

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree that writing data to external storage is not secure. Actually I'd like to save my unique id which is generated by me. Is there anything like iOS keychain in Android which I can save my data and it can last even I delete my app.

Comment: I don't know of one (but that's not a definitive  no). Based on what you've just said I'd do something like ask for users phone number,  then use the hash of that as a UUID. That way when they reinstall you'll get the hash again without anything having been stored and you can use a local db for everything else

Comment: Or, create a hash via some method that's repeatable, store that and the uuid on a web server and when they reinstall recreate the hash and go to the web service to check if you already have a uuid before creating one

Comment: If you've now come to a conclusion as a result of these answers please mark one as accepted

Comment: Your solution did answer my question. But it's actually not what I want because my purpose is to save the unique device id. The UUID in all your methods are not device related. (Ok, you can say the phone number is unique. But my application can't get the phone number of the device).Anyway I accept your answer because my question is not that clear.

Comment: if you allow me a small correction, the UUID **are** device related, because the unique MAC address is on the code composition, as detailed on [RFC 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing it is syncing the data with the cloud and restoring it if the user reinstalls the app.  You may want to look at leveraging the [BackupManager](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).